# Laravel remove header from JSON response

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4

I am using the following code to return a Json encoded response from a function.

```
return response()->json($returnArray);
```

However the reponse is as follow and include the HTTP headers:

```
Cache-Control: no-cache, private
Content-Type:  application/json
Date:          Mon, 23 Oct 2017 15:34:59 GMT

{"status":"success"}
```

How can I set the response so the headers are not included and only include the JSON?

```
{"status":"success"}
```

Comment: Is there is any specific reason not to send headers with response? Without headers client might not know what to do with the data.

Answer (score 1):

I had the some problem as you.

In my case problem was in `string` return type hinting in method.

**Example:**

```
public function getJson(): string{
    return response()->json(['foo' => 'bar']);
}
```

So, I replaced `string` to `JsonResponse` and that's all - problem solved.

Maybe would helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
return response()->toJson([
    'status' => 'success',
], 201);
```

or:

```
return Response::json(['data' => $array],201);
```